# Where in the java compiler source code does the compiler look for .java files to compile

Tags: java, parsing, code-generation, javac

I am currently working on a project which will require knowledge of the java compiler source code.  I have never worked on a project this large before and I need some help.

I would like to find out in which part of the source code does the compiler actually look for and find a .java file to compile.

I have looked at the java compiler source code which is very large. I have found that the parsing and the code generation phases are independent of each other but I don't know where javac asks for a .java file and where that file is given to it.

Any help on this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: should it be in the first phase? lexical analytics -> semantic analytics -> (type checking) -> codegen. BTW, What do you mean by involving a lot of javac?

Comment: What do you mean by "which will involve a lot of javac"? Do you really need to be messing with the compiler itself?

Comment: You specify the location via the command line. Or is your question related to dynamically generating, compiling and loading code?

Comment: I have edited my question. Yes, my question is related to dynamically generating, compiling and loading the code.  Where does javac look for the .java files to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `javax.tools` package provides a Java-based interface to the Java compiler from your JDK ([JavaCompiler](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7u/jdk7u60-dev/langtools/file/968984941a94/src/share/classes/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.java)).

`JavaCompiler` uses a [JavaFileManager](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7u/jdk7u60-dev/langtools/file/968984941a94/src/share/classes/javax/tools/JavaFileManager.java)'s methods to find and access the source files to be compiled. The [StandardFileManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/tools/StandardJavaFileManager.html) (used by default) offers a getJavaFileObjectsFromFiles() method that provides iteration over all java files found in a given root.

The links above will take you to the JDK sources (in case you actually want to roll your own version after modifying those sources, read [this](https://github.com/alexkasko/openjdk-unofficial-builds#build-process-manual-builds)); and to the JavaDoc for `StandardFileManager`.